# Elastic terms query with emails not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to pass a list of emails in Elastic Search Query, So I tried below query to achieve that, but didn't get any result.

```
{
    "query": {
      "terms": {
        "email": [ "andrew@gmail.com", "michel@gmail.com" ]
      }
    }
}
```

When I used **id** instead of emails, that worked !

```
{
    "query": {
      "terms": {
        "id": [ 43, 67 ]
      }
    }
}
```

Could you please explain what's wrong with my email query and how make it works

Comment: Can you share the mapping of email field?

Comment: One of the probable reason of search not working as expected could be that email field is mapped to text instead of keyword.

Comment: Did you try to put email.keyword?

Comment: yes, email.keyword works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to recognize email addresses as single tokens you should use `uax_url_email` tokenizer.

[UAX URL Email Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html)

A working example:

**Mappings**

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_email_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter": ["lowercase", "stop"]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer":{
          "type": "uax_url_email"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_email_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "my_email_analyzer",
          "fields": {
            "keyword":{
              "type":"keyword"
            }
          }
        }

    }
  }
}
```

**POST few documents**

```
POST my_index/_doc/1
{
  "email":"andrew@gmail.com"
}

POST my_index/_doc/2
{
  "email":"michel@gmail.com"
}
```

**Search Query**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "andrew@gmail.com michel@gmail.com",
      "fields": ["email"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Results**

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.6931472,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.6931472,
        "_source" : {
          "email" : "andrew@gmail.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.6931472,
        "_source" : {
          "email" : "michel@gmail.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Another option is to use `keyword` type.

**Search Query**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "email.keyword": [
        "andrew@gmail.com",
        "michel@gmail.com"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In my opinion using the `uax_url_email` tokenizer is a better solution.

Hope this helps